# mdicon components icon names doesn't work in vue

Tags: vue.js, material-design, material-design-icons

I want to use mdicon component (see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdi-vue)). But there's no cheatsheet for the icon names. I tried to use this [cheatsheet](https://pictogrammers.github.io/@mdi/font/5.4.55/) but it's not working as well. The names don't work for icons with more than one word (e.g. arrow-left, flag-plus) but it does work for single word icons (e.g. hamburger, home, alert). Does anyone know the real cheatsheet for this mdicon component? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try, for example

```html
<template>
<mdicon :name="icon1"/>
<template/>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    icon1: 'mdi-share-variant-outline'
})
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try using two pairs of quotes  " 'arrow-left' "